# proof: $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}, b > a, c > 0 $, $\Rightarrow$ $bc > ac$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

i have to prove for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}, b > a, c > 0 $, that  $bc > ac$
For this i have two different solutions:

solution 1)
$bc > ac$
$bcc^{-1} > acc^{-1}$
$b > a$
$b - a > 0 $
I have multiplied by the inverse and substarcted a, and thereby shown, that $bc > ac$ implies $b-a > 0$, which is true (contained in the definition of $b > a$, which means that $b - a \in P$, where $P$ are positive reals)

solution 2)
$b-a, c \in P$
and thus $c(b-a) \in P$
therefore $bc - ca > 0$
$bc > ca$
here more directly showing, that $b-a$ and $c$, by virtue of beeing in $P$, implies that $bc > ac$

Are these both valid solutions ?

Comment: You may suppose $bc \leq ac$ and see what happens.

Comment: remember in part $1)$, $b>a$ is already your assumption. Further you need to connect your statements with equivalence relations and you have to argue in each step (e.g.here I use distributivity of the multiplication etc.)

Comment: 1) is doubly wrong.  Wrong direction. Also assumes multiplication by $c^{-1}$ preserves inequality, which is structurally the same as what we are trying to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In solution $1$:

1. You say that $bc>ac$ implies $bcc^{-1} > acc^{-1}$. Which axiom did you use to prove this?
2. You say that $bc > ac$ implies $b-a>0$, therefore it is true.

**WARNING** What you just commited was a very common logical fallacy. If you know that $A$ implies $B$ and you know that $B$ is true, you **CANNOT** say that $A$ is true!!!

Example:

> - If the sun rotates around the earth, then the suns position in the sky will change over time.
> - The suns position in the sky changes over time
> - Therefore, the sun rotates around the earth.

Solution $2$ is better, just explain:

- What is the reason that $(b-a), c\in P$ implies that $c(b-a)\in P$?

Other than that, solution $2$ looks OK.

Comment: 1) I think that in $bcc^{-1} > acc^{-1}$ I used what i'm trying to prove.

Comment: @JohnDeer I agree. So solution $1$ is doubly wrong. But hey, solution $2$ looks alright;)